# declaring application path as a static constant

Tags: android

I'm trying to declare all constants used by my application in a separate constants class. I'd like to declare the application path but can't figure out how to do it in a static way.

How do I replace the "this" to something that will let me get the path?

```
public static final String DL_PATH = this.getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/";
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do I replace the "this" to something that will let me get the path?

You don't. There is nothing that you can use for this.

You are welcome to assign the value to `DL_PATH` from `onCreate()` of a custom `Application`. Or, delete `DL_PATH` entirely and just call `getFilesDir()` as needed from your various components (e.g., `Activity`, `Service`).